# Sum and joined column data in same query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle DB and have the following query which throws the error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Query:

```
select sum(ct.TOT_CT), ct.CREAT_TS, ev.EVENT
    from REF_CT ct
    inner join EVENT ev on ev.EVENT_TYPE_ID = ct.EVENT_TYPE_ID
    where ct.TX = 'SomeText';
```

If I try to access the following individually, it works. As in calling sum separately, ct.CREAT_TS separately and so on.

The issue seems to be calling sum in this query. I plan to capture the output in an Object (Java if relevant). I expected the query to output  following. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
CREAT_TS                      EVENT          sum(ct.TOT_CT)
2019-04-02 01:33:46.227000    SOME_EVENT 1   8
2019-04-02 02:56:14.530000    SOME_EVENT 2
```

After Given answers, getting following results where the sum value is split per column:

```
CREAT_TS                      EVENT          sum(ct.TOT_CT)
2019-04-02 01:33:46.227000    SOME_EVENT 1   2
2019-04-02 02:56:14.530000    SOME_EVENT 2   6
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to put the total sum on each row:

```
select ev.EVENT, ct.CREAT_TS, sum(ct.TOT_CT), 
       sum(sum(ct.TOT_CT)) over ()
from REF_CT ct inner join
     EVENT ev
     on ev.EVENT_TYPE_ID = ct.EVENT_TYPE_ID
where ct.TX = 'SomeText'
group by ev.EVENT, ct.CREAT_TS;
```

I don't really recommend putting the value on only one row, but you can do that with window functions:

```
select ev.EVENT, ct.CREAT_TS, sum(ct.TOT_CT), 
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by ev.event order by ct.CREAT_TS)
             then sum(sum(ct.TOT_CT)) over ()
        end)
from REF_CT ct inner join
     EVENT ev
     on ev.EVENT_TYPE_ID = ct.EVENT_TYPE_ID
where ct.TX = 'SomeText'
group by ev.EVENT, ct.CREAT_TS
order by ev.EVENT, ct.CREAT_TS;
```

The `order by` is very important if you want the grand total on the first row defined by `CREAT_TS`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `group by` clause.

```
select sum(ct.TOT_CT), ct.CREAT_TS, ev.EVENT
    from REF_CT ct
    inner join EVENT ev on ev.EVENT_TYPE_ID = ct.EVENT_TYPE_ID
    where ct.TX = 'SomeText'
    group by ct.CREAT_TS, ev.EVENT;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but with one caveat. The sum value is split into 2 rows. Thus getting 2 and 6 values. Would I be able to just ignore the rows and get the result as 8 instead for that?

Answer (score 1):

If at least one aggregated column exists in the select list, you need to group by non-aggregated columns

```
select sum(ct.TOT_CT), ct.CREAT_TS, ev.EVENT
    from REF_CT ct
    inner join EVENT ev on ev.EVENT_TYPE_ID = ct.EVENT_TYPE_ID
    where ct.TX = 'SomeText'
    group by ct.CREAT_TS, ev.EVENT
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but with one caveat. The sum value is split into 2 rows. Thus getting 2 and 6 values. Would I be able to just ignore the rows and get the result as 8 instead for that?

Comment: I added the new output in the answer above. Not sure what you mean by input data. I am using the exact query you mentioned less changes to my actual column names.  ct.TOT_CT is of number type. CREAT_TS is timestamp and EVENT is a String.

Comment: @kang depending on the information you shared, `trunc(ct.creat_ts), max(ev.event), sum(ct.tot_ct) ... group by trunc(ct.creat_ts)` gives 8 as result of sum. Otherwise you need to split the corresponding values for `tot_ct`.